# How do I use isdigit() in python 3.8.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, built-in, digits

I'm using Python 3.8.5, but I'm getting

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it on string, not on int. E.g.:

```
print('5'.isdigit())
# True

print(int('5').isdigit())
# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```